# Nextjs google places autocomplete giving incorrect values

Tags: javascript, google-maps, next.js, axios, cors

I am trying to use google auto complete to get the names of mosques only in united kingdom, I am recieving data but its global and it is not for mosques,
Here is my code:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default async function GetMosques(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.input);
  const input = req.body.input;
  const apiKey = "mykey"; // Replace with your actual API key
  const apiUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json";

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(apiUrl, {
      params: {
        input,
        key: apiKey,
        types: "mosque", // Set the type to "mosque" to filter results to mosques
        componentRestrictions: {
          country: "uk",
        },
      },
    });

    console.log("server:", response.data.predictions);
    

    const predictions = response.data.predictions.map((prediction) => ({
      id: prediction.place_id,
      name: prediction.description,
    }));

    res.json(predictions);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching autocomplete suggestions:", error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
}
```

The data im getting:

```
{
    description: 'Sayedabad Bus Terminal Masjid, Dhaka - Mawa Hwy, Dhaka, Bangladesh',
    matched_substrings: [ [Object] ],
    place_id: 'ChIJubFsVbO5VTcRRpdyaZ6sXjE',
    reference: 'ChIJubFsVbO5VTcRRpdyaZ6sXjE',
    structured_formatting: {
      main_text: 'Sayedabad Bus Terminal Masjid',
      main_text_matched_substrings: [Array],
      secondary_text: 'Dhaka - Mawa Hwy, Dhaka, Bangladesh'
    },
    terms: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    types: [
      'mosque',
      'place_of_worship',
      'point_of_interest',
      'establishment'
    ]
  },
  {
    description: 'Sharjah Mosque - Sharjah - United Arab Emirates',
    matched_substrings: [ [Object] ],
    place_id: 'ChIJGb39ZXqL9T4ReU5jj0N0q6c',
    reference: 'ChIJGb39ZXqL9T4ReU5jj0N0q6c',
    structured_formatting: {
      main_text: 'Sharjah Mosque',
      main_text_matched_substrings: [Array],
      secondary_text: 'Sharjah - United Arab Emirates'
    },
    terms: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    types: [
      'mosque',
      'place_of_worship',
      'point_of_interest',
      'establishment'
    ]
  }
```

the types is correct as it includes mosque but everything else is weird. The name of the mosque is not present and the data is from other countries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using parameters wrong, Here is the correct version:

```
const response = await axios.get(apiUrl, {
      params: {
        input: input,
        key: apiKey,
        types: "mosque", 
        components: "country:uk", // Set the country to the UK
      },
    });
```